# References in Riemannian geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I want to study Riemannian geometry but I don't know a perfect book for beginners, can you give me  references in riemannian geometry for beginners?

Comment: What prerequisites do you have? Multivariable Calculus? Smooth manifolds? Some knowledge of differential geometry for curves and surfaces?

Comment: Here are some more for a biggner: [$(1)$](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Semi_Riemannian_Geometry/uimpDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover) and [$(2)$](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/An_Introduction_to_Differentiable_Manifo/U19EgdcSQckC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover) and [$(3)$](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/Riemann.pdf) and [$(4)$](https://www.amazon.in/RIEMANNIAN-GEOMETRY-Concepts-Examples-Techniques/dp/B07VCT6S46/ref=sr_1_1?crid=7DLQR6O3ARQT&dchild=1&keywords=kumaresan+riemannian+geometry&qid=1613241147&sprefix=Kumaresan+r%2Cstripbooks%2C312&sr=8-1)

Comment: "A panoramic view of Riemannian geometry" by Marcel Berger https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540653172